# Device width in phonegap android

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing an android application in phonegap / HTML5.

As its first step I am taking device's width using

```
var viewport = {
        width  : parseInt($(window).width()),
        height : parseInt($(window).height())
    };
alert(viewport.width);
```

But first time wile deploying its showing 320 as alert, but when I restart application its showing 0. after that oftenly showing 320 ( in rare )

How to get the actual width of the device permanently ?

Sorry for my typos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried this

```
$(function(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
           var windowWidth = $(window).width();
           var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is made every now and then. See my previous answer at, and read the blog article itself: [JavaScript+Phonegap+Android: screen.width returns bad (almost random) values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524669/javascriptphonegapandroid-screen-width-returns-bad-almost-random-values/11527681#11527681)

Hope this helps you out.